# Why can I extend this class with a different name?

Tags: php, prestashop

in prestashop 1.6 (but I guess it's just a desing pattern), there a main class interface defined like this:

```
abstract class ObjectModelCore implements Core_Foundation_Database_EntityInterface
```

But then, when you want create an ObjectModel, you do like this:

```
class CustombannersBannerbox extends ObjectModel
```

Well, I cannot understand why. I mean, if the ObjectModelCore is called, well, ObjectModelCore, why can I extend it calling it ObjectModel?

Comment: `ObjectModel` and `ObjectModelCore` are different classes, you've missed something.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/1.6.0.9/tools/profiling/ObjectModel.php

Comment: Aioros, you should put it as the answer